# Highcharts Multiple series with database

Tags: javascript, database, highcharts

I ask for for some help since I can't find another thread to resolve my problem. I'm using HighCharts to render one chart with temperature and humidity values, saved on a local database. Each values comes with its type (`temp` or `humi`), the sensor which made the measurement, the `datetime` to know when it was taken, and the id of coefficients that come to calculate the real temp and humi values.
What I wants to render a chart where each serie is a sensor, with the two types of values the sensor saved on my database.
I can have up to 24 sensors with 24 temps and 24 humis with the same datetime in the database

First I don't know if I can do some objects definitions to use them directly in HighCharts, so for now, I have plenty of array.
I don't understand the way that series options work, there are a lot of things and I'm lost. I just switched from C++ to JS and PHP so it is hard for me to change my habits ^^

Can't upload my table here, but I can host it [here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/18Xt6.png)

If it's not possible to make only one chart, can I do two charts: one with temperatures an done with humidities in one (like with a tab?).

Thank you :)

---

**EDIT:** Here is my JSON to test the chart :

{"type":["temp","humi","temp","humi","temp","humi","temp","humi"],"capteur":["1","1","3","3","1","1","3","3"],"date":["1432654910","1432654910","1432654910","1432654910","1432742599","1432742599","1432742599","1432742599"],"valeur":["6626","1220","6357","1168","6782","1118","6329","994"],"coeff":["0","0","0","0","0","0","0","0"]}

Here my JS function to transform the JSON to the array I need :

function arrangeData(data) :

```
    var result = {
        "temp" : {
            "capteur" : [[], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], []], "date" : []
        }, 
        "humi" : {
            "capteur" : [[], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], []], "date" : []
        }
    };
    for(var i in data.type){
        if(data.type[i].localeCompare("temp") == 0){
            result.temp.capteur[data.capteur[i] - 1].push(data.valeur[i]);
            if(result.temp.date.length != 0){
                if(result.temp.date[result.temp.date.length - 1].getTime() != data.date[i] * 1000)
                    result.temp.date.push(new Date(data.date[i] * 1000));
            }
            else
                result.temp.date.push(new Date(data.date[i] * 1000));
        }
        else{
            result.humi.capteur[data.capteur[i] - 1].push(data.valeur[i]);
            if(result.humi.date.length != 0){
                if(result.humi.date[result.humi.date.length - 1].getTime() != data.date[i] * 1000)
                    result.humi.date.push(new Date(data.date[i] * 1000));
            }
            else
                result.humi.date.push(new Date(data.date[i] * 1000));
        }
    }
    console.log(result);
    return result;
```

And I pass the "result" to `setChart` like this :

setChart(chart_temp, name, data.temp.date, data.temp.capteur);

Comment: The simplest way is prepare any script (like php) which get data from database and form a JSON (by json_encode()) function. Then in javascript you can call $.getJSON() with url to your php and assing data to chart.

Comment: Okay I will do that, but how do I have to arrange my json to use it with HighCharts ?
1) like [ [ 1, 2, 3 ... 24 ][ 2015-06-02, 2015-06-02 ... ] [ 6023, 6101 ... ] ... ] ? or
2) like [ [1, 2015-06-02, 6023 ...][2, 2015-06-02, 6101] ...] ?

Comment: For each point it should be array like [x,y] where x is timestamp (time in miliseconds) and y is value.

Comment: But I have to show 24 lines for 24 sensors. Can I do [x, y] for each sensor where each sensor is a serie in my chart ?

Comment: Each serie contains data array of points. Each point needs to be array of x/y values.

Comment: ok, made some change in my code, but I don't get any line and no more error :/ I use a little function that I found on stack and modified it a bit:
`function setChart(chart, name, categories, data);`
I pass the y values in "categories", and an array of x values in "data", but no line :( I have same number of x and y values for each series, so I don't understand why it doesn't work ...

Comment: In case when you modify something, please add also a JSON because we have no information how it looks like at current moment.

Comment: Did an edit on my first post

Comment: A few clues 1) timestamps should be numbers (not strings as you have) and multiplied by 1000 (javascript timestamps instead of unix, 2)You should have pairs x/y instead of two arrays. So prepare a parser which use loop over each elemetn and then initalise chart

Comment: 1) It actually work how i did it, so I don't get what you want me to do ^^ ,
2) Okay I can do that, but what will I have to do with it ? What about the "categories" of the charts, no more used ?

Comment: You can use categories, but as I see you have timesstamps, so better is using datetime type of xAxis. Timestamps will be replcaed with dates correcty.

Comment: So no need to use `new Date()` if I understand correctly, and just passing [x, y] for each series and HighCherts will do the rest ?

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to Sebastian Bochan, I can now use HighCharts with my datas downloaded from a PHP file that output JSON data.

I have to parse the JSON data in an array, in that way :
`data:{ temp:{ [datetime, value], ...}, humi:{ [datetime, value], ...}};`
The `x` axis is datetimes, and the `y` axis is values reported by my sensors.

In the charts, I do a `chart.addSeries({name: name[i], data: data[i]});` in a `for` loop, where `chart` is the chart I want to set, `name` is an array of name for each series and `data` is the array of `[datetime, value]` like `temp` or `humi` arrays.